# Nightwatch starts selenium and then hangs indefinitely

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm running a simple nightwatch test on a Windows 10.1 machine. The tests starts up selenium server (e.g., selenium server... started - PID: 12784), but it never gets to the test code. I can use a browser to get to the localhost server page that is spawned from the "node nightwatch.js -t test.js" command, so I know the server is working properly. I've also tried running nightwatch with different browsers, e.g., -e chrome, firefox, IE, and phantomjs, and none of them work. Putting --verbose on the command doesn't provide any more console spew, so not sure how to debug this. I'm running with selenium-server-standalone v2.53.0.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own problem. Turns out the problem was with incompatible versions of node, nightwatch, and python. I figured it out by creating a totally separate clone of my repository and reinstalling all the node/nightwatch/selenium dependencies. Would be nice if there was a debug feature that could be enabled to indicate more details about where a node or nightwatch application is during application startup. I learned of node-inspector, so I'll check it out as a possible debug tool.

Comment: Hi, what's your working version of node/nightwatch/selenium/phantomjs ? I have the same problem, but it's working fine with chromedriver.

Comment: nightwatch 0.7.11
selenium-server-standalone-jar 2.53.0
phantomjs 1.9.7-15

The current setup doesn't work with firefox, but it's a different problem.